# How to specify that type is class or protocol

Tags: class, swift

```
import Foundation


@objc public protocol ObjcProtocol {
}
```

It shows the following error:

Inheritance from non-protocol, non-class type 'A'
    public func someFunc(a: A.Type, b: B) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

```
func someFunc(a: AnyObject.Type, b: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return false
}


protocol MyProtocol: ObjcProtocol {
}


class MyBaseClass: MyProtocol {
}


class MyDerivedClass: MyBaseClass {
}

someFunc(ObjcProtocol.self, MyBaseClass())
```

What should I do?

Comment: How are `A` and `B` declared? `A` has to be either a protocol or a class for you to use it as a generic constraint.